# Latexindent with Homebrew Perl and Sublime Text

Tags: mac, sublime-text, perl, latexindent

I'm trying to get the package BeautifyLatex working on Sublime Text 3. My initial attempts revealed that certain Perl modules were missing which prevented latexindent from working. Instead of fiddling about with the native Perl installation I made a homebrew perl installation and linked the perl command to this and installed the missing modules. I found that Latexindent worked from the command line however still wouldn't work through the Sublime BeautfyLatex package.

According to the [Github page instructions](https://github.com/ketan/BeautifyLatex>GitHub) I tested to see if "latexindent was functional":

"*To check this, go to the terminal, cd to the directory containing your latexindent, and type perl latexindent. If your latexindent is functional, you shall see its version information*"

Doing this gave the output

```
Cannot write to 'indent.log': Permission denied at /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.0/Log/Dispatch/File.pm line 101.
```

At this point I am way out of my depth. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello! Can you access the command line options of latexindent through the beautifylatex software? If so, perhaps you could use the -c=<directory> option to redirect the writing of the log file

Comment: @cmhughes I can't access the command line through the software as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem by installing the package directly from GitHub as the package creator suggests instead of using Sublime's package manager.